# Dynamic column name mapped to another table for copying the data

Tags: sql, oracle

Source table contains data for the last 2 years, e.g.:

```
column name: aug_16, sep_16 ... oct_17 ... jul_18, aug_18
```

Column name changes every month - one column is added and one is deleted.

For example, next month column started from:
`sep_16` to `sep_18` which means that `aug_16` will be deleted and `sep_18` will be added.

So my issue is: I want to copy data to another `Interface` table and want to do mapping in ODI jobs before loading to Base table. How should I handle dynamic column name?

Comment: You should fix your data model.  Adding and removing columns from tables is not a good approach.  Each month should be stored on a separate row.  You can aggregate the data as needed to get 12 months into a table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your best option is to abandon such a data model and create a new one. Instead of doing everything in DDL, do it in DML. What I mean to say: alter table and add a `DATE` datatype column. It will show which month/year that row belongs to. Then, it is a simple matter of a `WHERE` clause which will handle data.

```
Instead of: update interface set sep_16 = (select sep_16 from base)

You would : insert into interface select * from base
                                  where to_char(date_column, 'yyyymm') = '201609'
```

This is just an example, written for simplicity of the general idea; such a `WHERE` will *ruin* possible index on `DATE_COLUMN`, but that can be handled (by using `BETWEEN` first and last day of the month, for example)